# Inserting dylib into existing bundle/executable

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have an existing bundle/executable, which I need to add a new dylib into.

Methods I've already tried:

- Copying dylib into bundle & setting dyld_insert_libraries within info.plist to load library. This works with the one issue that I won't be able to control the location of the app/bundle (or library if outside bundle) and relative paths (e.g @executable_path) can't be used in info.plist.
- Using install_name_tool (-add_rpath, -id, etc) to add a new path to the library. This just doesn't seem to work unless theres a path in there to change. (The name/install location of the library is correct and been checked many times).

Are there any further solutions to this problem or even modifications on the solutions (above) that I've already tried?

Comment: When using `install_name` to set the `@executable_path` of the binary there **is** a path to use: `../Frameworks`.

Comment: Can this be used to ADD a new path to a library though. This doesn't seem to work. Changing the path of an existing library/framework is fine but not adding a new one.

Comment: So the app isn't one of yours, that you compile and link yourself?

Comment: No, it's an app provided to us by clients. This method allows us to remove integration time for clients by letting us complete the process for them (just with a supplied bundle)

Answer (score 3):

I've made a tool that can do that called `insert_dylib`: https://github.com/Tyilo/insert_dylib

Here's the usage info:

```
Usage: insert_dylib [--inplace] [--weak] dylib_path binary_path [new_path]
```

And how to use it:

```
 $ insert_dylib /usr/lib/libfoo.dylib test
 The provided dylib path doesn't exist. Continue anyway? [y/n] y
 Added LC_LOAD_DYLIB command to test_patched
 $ diff -u <(otool -hl test) <(otool -hl test_patched)
 ...
```

Comment: dyld_interpose doesn't seem to work in libraries added this way, as they do with DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES. Is this just an inherent limitation? I guess because the new library is loaded last, or some such?

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the environment variable DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES to point the library you want to inject when executing the binary. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/dyld.1.html for details.

Comment: Really?  So you instruct the user to set that environment variable before using `open /path/to/app`?  Poor user.

Comment: What an unhappy experience for them :(

Comment: I don't see why it would make any difference to users whether the thing they start is the actual executable or a wrapper that sets things up and then starts the actual executable. The interaction is the same.

Comment: Well there are logistical problems if you want to provide the app, dylib and wrapper script separately which are completely eliminated by bundling the dylib with the app (something which is well supported).

Comment: Ideally this wouldn't use a wrapper as that's a solution I'm already using but is becoming messy.